# Mocha not stopping after supertest when using express server

Tags: mocha.js, supertest

I have a simple supertest test using mocha like this.

```
describe("test", () =>{
  it("Test 1", (done) =>{
    let app = (new App()).express;
    supertest(app).get("/").expect(200, done);
  })
})
```

The test runs and passes but never shuts down mocha. I tried this.

```
describe("test", () =>{
  it("Test 1", (done) =>{
    let app = (new App()).express;
    supertest(app).get("/").expect(200, ()=>{
      app.close();
      done();
    });
  })
})
```

But `app.close` is not declared and I am not rolling up a whole server. How do I get mocha to stop after the test?

Comment: Note adding the --exit flag does seem to work but is that the real solution?

Comment: Instead of using short hand `() => {}`, try using `function()` since mocha seems to have issues when passing arrow functions

Answer (score 1):

Here is an minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.info(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

module.exports = server;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const supertest = require("supertest");

describe("test", () => {
  after((done) => {
    app.close(done);
  });

  it("Test 1", (done) => {
    supertest(app)
      .get("/")
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:3000
  test
    ✓ Test 1


  1 passing (23ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Start the HTTP server:

```sh
☁  mocha-chai-sinon-codelab [master] ⚡  node /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/src/stackoverflow/53048031/app.js                 
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:3000
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/53048031

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$ mocha --exit
```

or add

```
"exit": true
```

in .mocharc

source: [github link](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http/issues/178#issuecomment-336602457)